# Как спарсить время и дату из сообщения в телеграмм боте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, datetime, telebot

Для своей разработки бота мне необходимо выделить время и дату из сообщения пользователя и присвоить их отдельным переменным.

Подскажите как это лучше всего реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

`message.date` вернет вам время в формате `1588974616`. Это секунды, прошедшие с  1 января 1970.

Comment: Судя по документации, `message.date` это `datetime` тип https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.date

Comment: Вы приводите документацию к библиотеке, что не указана в ваших тегах. Либо выставьте релевантные теги, либо узнайте, почему библиотеки бывают разные.

Comment: print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(message.date).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))